# select latest 2 records of each product id in single table

Tags: sql

this is my table structure,

```
create table ArticleTbl
(
ArticleID bigint identity(1,1),
ProductID int ,
ArticleName varchar(100),
PubDate datetime,
AuthorName varchar(50),
AuthorImage bit,
HtmlValues nvarchar(max)
)
```

here productid are

```
1=creditcard,2=prepaidcard,3 saving account,.........
```

each productid is having multiple rows of records ,
i want to select latest 2 records of each productid in one shot instead of going to database each time .

my procedure now is like..

```
create proc USP_GetArticle_ByProduct(@ProductID int) as 
select top(2) * from ArticleTbl where ProductID=@ProductID
```

if i use this procedure each productid i have to go to database...

how to get one shot all product(latest 2 records ) using query????

Comment: Any chance you can fix the formatting?

Comment: I also fixed the title: it said 2 rows in the body but 3 rows in title

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        /*Random order per product*/
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY NEWID() ) AS Ranking,
        *
    FROM
        ArticleTbl
    ) foo
WHERE
   foo.Ranking <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

i figure this is on sql server yeah?

if so, you could do this...

```
select  a1.*
from Articletbl a1
where a1.articleid in
    (select top 2 a2.articleid 
    from ArticleTbl a2
    where a2.productid = a1.productid
    order by a2.articleid DESC)
order by a1.ProductID
```